# Use Spring options tag to display enum's toString value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, enums

I'm using Spring for an HTML form. One of the fields is an `enum` and thus I'd like a HTML drop-down list (`<option>` tag). My enum's name is different than the `toString()` value. For example:

```
public enum Size {
    SMALL("Small"), LARGE("Large"), VERY_LARGE("Very large");

    private final String displayName;

    private Size(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

I want the user to see the `toString()` value. Normally this is accomplished using the `itemLabel` of the Spring options tag.

```
<form:options items="${enumValues}" itemLabel="beanProperty" />
```

But `toString()` isn't a bean property as it doesn't start with "get". Is there a way to set `itemLabel` to use toString's value without having to create a getter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is few years old and must be solved by now, but thought I'd add the solution for future comers.

Just remove the [itemLabel="beanProperty"] part. It will use the toString to print the values.

Comment: This used to work in 3.0, but has been broken since 3.1, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9214 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10281

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a public getDisplayName() method to your enum?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding this extra method to each enum. It doesn't help that enum can't be extended.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Spring's powerful AOP model to extend your enums from one place? It would seem that, depending on how many enums you have, you could easily add a `getDisplayName()` method to all of them that simply returns their `toString()` value.